# Is there a way to convert a varchar column in dd-mm-yyyy format to a date column in yyyy-mm-dd format in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date

I am working on PostgreSQL.

I have a column named `curr_date` in my table. The datatype previously assigned to it is `varchar` but the column stores dates in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Now I want to change its datatype to date but in order to do that i first have to convert all the values in the column in `dd-mm-yyy` format to `yyy-mm-dd` format.

Only then can I use the query alter table alter column `curr_date` type date using `curr_date::date`;

so is there a way to convert this format. i am open to using dummy column to make the changes too.

Comment: Lets clear up a misconception inherent in your question. Dates are not stored in any format, but in an internal structure ([date 4bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-datetime.html), integer?, timestamp 8bytes, bigint?) which can be displayed in any valid format. So your question becomes "convert a varchar  column  with dates in the format dd-mm-yyyy to a date column".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a single statement:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
   ALTER col TYPE date USING to_date(col, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

That will explicitly convert the data from the old format to the new format.

A change like this will cause the table to be rewritten, which can take a while if the table is large. During that time, the table is inaccessible even for `SELECT` statements.